# Listing all programs installed on Mac using Java

Tags: java, macos, installed-applications

How can I list all the installed programs on Mac OS, date of installation and version using Java?

For example, on Windows I use `wmic get product name, version, InstallDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump
```

or

```
ls -hal /Applications/
grep -i CFBundleShortVersionString -A 1 /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dump of all the applications registered with Launch Services using,

```
    lsregister -dump
```

Execute this command through your java applications and read the dump file to get the app names.